# How to select a line in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am unable to select a line in cygwin, atleast by using the traditional windows method of clicking and dragging the mouse curser across the line that i would like to select.

Is there a specific package that i need to install to be able to select a line of code in cygwin? or is there just another linux way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to press shift and L mousebutton to select a text.

Comment: are you using the Cygwin terminal ?

Comment: yes, but from a different console with tabs.

Comment: but it is solved

Answer (score 0):

**Enable Mark Mode:**

- Hold **Alt**
- Press **Space**
- Select **Edit**
- Click **Mark**

This will enter "Mark Mode" and allow you to select lines in the terminal screen.

**To Paste:**

This is pretty straight forward:

- Click and drag your selection
- **Right Click** to copy
- **Right Click** again to paste (in the terminal), or just ctrl + v in another app to paste from clipboard

What you're looking for is bullet number 2.  Once selected, right clicking will save this to your Windows clipboard.  Right clicking in the cygwin terminal again will paste (if no selection is currently highlighted).

Comment: my problem is that i am unable to select a line.

Comment: My apologies, misread the original post, check for the update

Comment: my apologies, that i am stupid and didnt research all that i could,  before coming here.

Comment: No need to apologize!  This forum is meant for questions :)